# Escaping characters by doubling them in PHP

Tags: php, escaping, quotes

Is there a simple way to escape/unescape an arbitrary character in PHP by doubling it, for example:

- in ANSI SQL, `"you can ""escape"" this way"`
- in printf(), `you can express a %% this way`

Escaping is quite easy with `str_replace()`, but reversing the process to unescape the string is not that easy, so does anyone know of a pair of functions, or a library to do this?

The idea is that I need to serialize an array this way:

`array('a','b', '~','c')` => `'a~b~~~~c'`

The individual strings *cannot be empty*.

**Update**: just realized that this "encoding" is broken, thanks to the useful comments below.

Comment: How many characters you have to escape?

Comment: `a~b~~~~c` is ambiguous so you are asking the impossible. e.g., It could be two elements: `a,b~~c`. Why not just use `serialize` or `json_encode`?

Comment: `'a~b~~~~c'` This doesn't work. What about `array('a', 'b~~c')`? Why not use `serialize()` to serialize an array?

Comment: @konforce: I considered both options but they don't fit my precise need. About your comment, there is no ambiguity and the process is 100% reversible. A `~` not followed by another `~` is a delimiter, while `~~` is a normal `~` character.

Comment: @phant0m: same comment. `array('a', 'b~', 'c')` would translate to `a~b~~~c`, which is 100% reversible.

Comment: Yes, I had already noticed and adjusted accordingly. Now seeing taht I ended up with the same as konforce. Why doesn't serialize() fit your need? If you would tell us *what* you want to solve instead of *how*, it might work better.

Comment: Your encoding is broken. There are multiple ways to resolve your encoded data into an array again based on that char, so it's not possible to solve that. What should be done if the string can not be decoded? Create the maximum or minimum elements possible?

Comment: @Benjamin, `array('a','b', '~','c') => 'a~b~~~~c'`. `array('a','b~~c') => 'a~b~~~~c'`. Explain how it is not ambiguous to have two inputs that create the same output.

Comment: @phant0m: please forget `serialize()` and `json_encode()`. I know I could use them but specifically don't want to.

Comment: @hakre: I added the requirement that the strings cannot be empty. I understand that if they can, the encoding is broken. I trust that is they can't, then there it no ambiguity anymore.

Comment: @konforce: you broke it. Damn it :)

Comment: There are no empty strings in the counterexample. Again: Explain what you're trying to achieve, not how!

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to provide a readable scalar representation of an entity's identifier, which can be itself scalar (`123` **or** `ABC`) or compound (`123,ABC`). The requirement is that I don't want a simple scalar identifier like `ABC` to be represented as a quoted string, the quoting would become visible only if the identifier contains special chars.

Comment: Define: 1.) readable, 2.) entity, 3.) identifier, 4.) compound. And that's only your first sentence. I have no clue at all what you talk about. I can only say that your idea is screwed because you're mixing encoding of a string like the SQL / prinf example and encoding of a composition of strings. You can not make an apple become a banana only because you want it to be.

Comment: @hakre: 1) For simple use cases (say letters and figures), the encoded identifier should be the identifier itself. 2) Entity = domain model object in DDD. 3) Identifier = Object's identity, it's a string. 4) Compound = more than one string composes it. But this will end up out of the question context I'm afraid.

Comment: 1.) Is not a definition but something you wish to be. You can just proof that by looking at the example you give in the question: It's broken. So you ask for something you can not even give an example for! Give an example that looks working and we can look if a proof in form of an algorithm is possible. But your req. already failed at the very first step. So back to start and give a working example at least.

Comment: I also mean by readable that `(123,ABC)` should be represented as something like `123~ABC`.

Comment: @hakre: I understand that the encoding is broken, so back to the drawing board. I guess the real question is not "improve my code please" then, but rather "how can I do that"! I'll start a new question to better ask for this.

Comment: No sooner said than done :-) [Provide a human-readable representation of an identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444404/provide-a-human-readable-representation-of-an-identifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several users pointed it out in the comments, this question is flawed and has no possible answer.

A detailed explanation of my goal, and an appropriate answer have been provided at [Provide a human-readable representation of an identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444404/provide-a-human-readable-representation-of-an-identifier)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that

```
str_replace($char, $char.$char, $string);
```

and

```
str_replace($char.$char, $char, $string);
```

would be the complements of each other.

Comment: I updated my question to put an example of what I need. I want to use `$char` as a delimiter to convert back to an array, but want `$char.$char` to be treated as a single `$char` and not as a two delimiters.

Comment: Not sure you'd be able to make this work. You're dual purposing your escape character as both escape AND as separator. Given `~~~~` is it `,~,`, `,,,,`, `,,~`, etc...

Comment: `~~~~` is `~~`, the same way `%%%%` is `%%` in printf() and `""""` is `""` in an ANSI SQL identifier.

Comment: sorry, I know what you mean now. I forgot to say that the individual strings cannot be empty, which I guess solves the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`addcslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) and `stripcslashes` which will allow you to slash those characters you want to. That's maybe helpful.

Next to that your question does not really say where exactly you see a problem in unescaping, so I can not offer anything else than using the `str_replace` in reverse.

Comment: I specifically don't want to use backslashes at all. I just updated my question with an example of what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_split() with

```
(?<!-)-(?!-)|(?:-)((?:-{2})+)(?:-)
```

You have to use the flag PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE.
After some struggling, I am quite surprised that there actually is a regex solution for this.

```
a-b----c-hl--g------lo-x
```

becomes

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => -- [3] => c [4] => hl--g [5] => ---- [6] => lo [7] => x )
```

Comment: You may have noticed that I use the delimiter "-". Found this a bit more convenient. :) In my regex you can replace "-" with any other character but remember to escape special regex characters with backslash.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, however as we exchanged on the question comments I realized that the problem itself was broken (see these comments for the reasons why).