# Provide a human-readable representation of an identifier?

Tags: php, orm, domain-driven-design, identity, identifier

As a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443607/escaping-characters-by-doubling-them-in-php) where I asked for a solution to a broken problem, I'm trying to find a way to express an arbitrary identifier in a "readable" way.

Context: we are working with *entities* (domain model objects from [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)), which have an *identity*. This identity (mapped to a database primary key) can be expressed as a string: `'123'`, `'ABC'`.

Some *entities* can have a *compound identity*, i.e. composed of two or more other entities' *identity*: `array('123','ABC')`.

Sometimes, we want to pretty-print this *identity*, or to use it in a place where just a single string is allowed (for example, in an HTML `<option>` value). The process has to be predictable and reversible, i.e. there should be no ambiguity in how to reverse it back to its original state.

When we want to human-read this *identity*, for debugging purposes, it's easier to read `123`, `ABC`, or `123~ABC` rather than `a:2:{i:0;s:3:"123";i:1;s:3:"ABC";}`, that's why we don't want to use built-in functions such as `serialize()` or `json_encode()`.

json_encode() does a pretty good job, but when it comes to use it in HTML, where quotes have to be properly encoded, it becomes quite unreadable:

```
<option value="[&quot;123&quot;,&quot;ABC&quot;]">
```

Where we could use a nice format just like this one:

```
<option value="123~ABC">
```

When posting the HTML form, we have to be able to revert this encoded *identity* to its original state: `array('123','ABC')` to retrieve the correct *entity*.

Finally, it is perfectly acceptable that the format becomes complicated to (humanly) read if the *identity* contains other chars than letters and figures.

Some basic examples:

`'123'` => `'123'`
`'ABC'` => `'ABC'`
`array('123','ABC')` => `'123~ABC'` (just an idea)

`'string with non-alphanumeric, even non-àscìì char$'` => `?`

Any (more or less complicated) representation is acceptable for strings containing other chars. The resulting string should contain only ASCII chars, even if the original string contains non-ASCII chars. The whole process must be entirely reversible.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What are valid characters for the entities?

Comment: Any character is valid for an *identity*, as it is in a database string primary key. In real life though, it is most of the time made of readable characters. That's why the encoding should accomodate both.

Comment: So about which charset are you talking then? Is it expressable in Unicode codepoints?

Comment: Good point. The charset should not matter. If the original string contains non-ASCII chars, then it would be a good solution to encode them so that they fit in the ASCII charset, as well. I updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the feedback you gave in the comments I would suggest that you encode identifier-atoms with [urlencode](http://php.net/function.urlencode) or [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/function.urlencode)

You can then create atom-composition by using `,` colons.

```
class Identifier {
    static function encode(array $identifier) {
        return implode(', ', array_map('rawurlencode', $identifier));
    }
    static function decode($identifier) {
        return array_map('rawurldecode', 
            array_map('trim', explode(',', $identifier))
        );
    }
}

$identifier = array('111', 'abc');
var_dump($identifier);

$encoded = Identifier::encode($identifier);
var_dump($encoded);

$decoded = Identifier::decode($encoded);
var_dump($decoded);
```

Comment: That's a very interesting and simple way, it does solve the problem as expressed above, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this well-written code, it's rare enough to highlight it. I'd just remove the space after the comma (not useful IMO), and that seems to solve my problem perfectly: `return implode(',', array_map('rawurlencode', $identifier));` and `return array_map('rawurldecode', explode(',', $identifier));`.

Comment: Well consider that others might edit these identifiers in files and might add whitespace around. Hence the trim. Strict in output, but non-strict in accepting input.

Comment: I can't see a use case where users would have to **edit** the identifiers, but why not, I understand your point. Both approaches are valid, though I might favor the simplest one, for the human- **readable** requirement (human- **writable** is less an issue for now). Many thanks for your help, that's an excellent job!

Comment: Class used as namespace? it's a no-no :)

Comment: @yes123: He's not writing a book on OOP patterns, he's using a simple & clear way to present his answer. We could also argue on your hacky `str_replace()` over `json_encode()`...

Comment: hacky? XD that's a simple string replacing

Comment: @yes123: PHP used for programming? It's a no-no, get a real language.

Comment: @hakre: i guess you are ironic there considering your last activity? next time add a smile i will get that better

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace( array('[',']','&quot;',',') ,
             array('','','','~'),
            json_encode($stuff)
);
```

Your questions is utterly verbous and doenst' explain what you really want to achive.

Comment: lol, exactly the opposite of the comments in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443607/escaping-characters-by-doubling-them-in-php), that explains the verbosity. I think it does explain well what I'm trying to achieve, I just added another sentence to the question, maybe it wasn't that obvious: "when posting the HTML form, when have to be able to revert that to its original state to retrieve the correct entity". About your code, you don't explain how you reverse it?

Comment: @Benjamin: edit your question (delete everything and) post an array of example and exactly how you want to transform it. I will edit my answer too accordingly

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I will add a few examples, but won't delete the question, people from the previous question did want to understand the context of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 special characters:

`~` - delimiter

`*` - escape character (to escape a delimiter or an escape character itself)

Examples:

```
array('123','ABC') => 123~ABC
array('12*3','A~BC') => 12**3~A*~BC
```

You can choose different characters for delimiter and escape character. If selected characters will be rarely usable then the string usually will be well readable.